# Compute variance, using explicit PDF

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to get $\text{Var}(x)$ of $f(x) = 2(1+x)^{-3},\ x>0$.

Please tell me if my working is correct and/or whether there is a better method I can use to get this more easily.

$$
\text{Var}(x) = E[X^2] - [E[X]]^2
$$
and
$$E[X] = \int_0^{\infty}2\frac{x}{(x+1)^3}dx$$

Let $u = x+1$

$du = dx$

When $x=0, u = 0 + 1 = 1$
\begin{align}
$E[X] &= 2\int_1^\infty \frac{u-1}{u^3}du\\
&= 2[\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{u^2}du-\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^3}du]\\
&= 2[[-\frac{1}{u}]_1^\infty-[-\frac{1}{2u^2}]_1^\infty]\\
&=2[[0-(-\frac{1}{1})]-[0-(-\frac{1}{2(1)^2})]]\\
&=2[1-\frac{1}{2}]\\
&=1\\
\end{align}
$$E[X^2] = \int_0^{\infty}2\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^3}dx$$

Now I'm stuck

I tried to say. $u = x+1$. $x = u-1$. $x^2 = u^2-2u+1$ and substitute but then I get $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u} = [\ln|u|]_0^\infty$ for one of the terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $$E(X^2)=\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)\mathrm dx.$$ If, as is the case here, when $x\to+\infty$, $$f(x)\sim\frac{c}{x^a},$$ for some positive $c$, with $a\leqslant3$, then the integral defining $E(X^2)$ diverges hence the variance of $X$ does not exist.

Comment: This is a test question. Do you think that's what they expected us to say?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Thanks. It just seemed a bit unlikely. I thought I made an error

Answer (score 1):

Since the integral defining $\text{E}\left[X^2\right]$ diverges, one sometimes expresses that by saying the second moment does not exist. Consequently, its variance also doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that $\text{E}\left[X^2\right]$ does **not** converge to $\infty$ and that one **always** expresses "that" by saying the second moment does not exist.

Comment: Sorry to insist but the assertion (in the revised version) that "the second moment $\text{E}\left[X^2\right]$ might diverge to $+\infty$" is still meaningless. (And "its variant" should probably read "its variance".)

Comment: @Did Sorry for the late reply and my messy grammar. I said $\text{E}\left[X^2\right]\to\infty$ but I am wondering, why did you say "$\text{E}\left[X^2\right]$ does **not** converge to $\infty$"? Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: Because $\text{E}\left[X^2\right]$ neither goes to ∞ nor fails to go to ∞, it is just a number.

Comment: @Did Sorry, I don't still understand. Could you please elaborate more specific? IMHO, the integral representation of the 2nd moment diverges or tends to infinity

Comment: Let me suggest that you address *what was written when I wrote my comment* (otherwise, your request that I am more "specific" could appear as a typical evasion tactics). And no, "the expectation diverges" and "the expectation converges to infinity" are not synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Note $x^2 = (x+1)^2 - 2 x - 1$. Writing it like that should make the integral much easier. Though I'm sure you'll find what Did said.